# Android communication between multi apk

Tags: android

I want to create an android game and I want to divide it on 3 layers. First layer is authentication layer with CustomAuthenticator visible in Settings->Accounts & Synch, second layer is a list of existing games or existings rooms and third layer is game itself. And each of those layers need to use HTTP. The question is whether HTTP handling need to be separately in each of those layers or enough will be one and the other layers will be using it? If I separate the project on to three apk there is many of reasons to use RMI, but I am not sure if this is a proper way to communicate between apk. Let's say that we have gaming application with custom authenticating, rooms with players and vary games. What is the best schema for something like this?

Comment: If your question is about communication between applications, Android uses the `Intent` mechanism for that. Read about it in the [Developer Guides](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html)

Comment: I know intent mechanism, but here is a little bit more, I think that Intents are not sufficient to achieve communication between maybe not app, but app and another app which is attached as library to first app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I separate the project on to three apk there is many of reasons to use RMI, but I am not sure if this is a proper way to communicate between apk

If you think **users** are going to download **three separate apps from the Play Store** just to run your game, you are completely off your rocker.

RMI does not exist in Android. For legitimate cases of application integration, there are tons of Android-capable options:

- linking activities
- communicating via services (commands or binding via AIDL)
- broadcast `Intents` and receivers
- `ContentProvider`

> Let's say that we have gaming application with custom authenticating, rooms with players and vary games. What is the best schema for something like this?

Use one APK.